# Some Microdisplacement(?) going wrong

Tags: cycles-render-engine, displacement

I had tried to use micropolygon displacement but ended up disabling it.
This is the preview rendered view:
[image]

But this is the final render:
[image]

What on earth is happening!?

Answer (score 1):

Micro displacement is sensitive to normals.
Make your model smooth (shading smooth) ensure normal continuity across edges.
Doing so will prevent displacement discontinuity on sharp edges.

Comment: Thank for the answer however I managed to put the problem down to a malfunctioning bevel modifier. But thanks for your input. ;)